# How configure base_url in codeigniter in server

Tags: php, codeigniter, server, config, base-url

I am using ipage hosting with multiple domain names which are indexing directories in the root directory. I have uploaded my codeigniter project to one of directories. I have changed the base_url configuration as follows.

changed from `localhost/mertics/` to `http://mertics.com/`

and tried with `http://mertics.com/Mertics`  (Mertics is the directory which mertics.com indexes)

But, it gives an error : '404 Page Not Found'

Comment: if Mertics is the directory which mertics.com indexes then no need to pass directoryname "Mertics" after url
is "Mertics" is controller name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make it sure that your file name under controllers are started with capital letter
2. Make it sure that your routes are correct.
3. make it sure that your .htaccess is correct

can you make more details about your problem? '404 Page Not Found'means that your file name under controller does not exist

Comment: however the project worked fine in localhost. I have changed only the base_url

Comment: do you have .htaccess in your codeigniter? can you check the php files under controller folder if its started with big letter? when your project publish online make it sure that your first letter of your php file name in controller are big letter or else that errors will appear

Comment: Yes. That was the mistake. But, when I call any function (Example : mertics.com/contact) it shows that :'No input file specified.'

Comment: that contact was inside the controller? and can you check if the file name and class name are the same name? maybe that was your mistake too

Comment: Maybe you should check your .htaccess. correcting the .htaccess may solve your problem

Comment: Yes. the contact function is inside the Controller. And both class name and file name are same.

Comment: This is .htaccess                                                                     <IfModule authz_core_module>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: This is index function : public function index(){

  $this->home();
 }                               home() is a function which is also inside the controller

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tdD24qyEsYhmMny-o3KxRU-FpetzSPzt download this and replace the RewriteBase /NMSCST_CLINIC_INFORMATION_SYSTEM/ to RewriteBase /mertics/

Comment: metrics is your project folder I guess